# javascript image slideshow, video like playback

Tags: javascript, html

I want to take a video and dump it into seperate frames and then create a Javascript/HTML5 player that can play through a sequence of images.

Key reasons I want to use images is to allow for an all keyframes style fast forward and rewind for use in a slow motion player and also for use in video editing where you need to be able to skip to any keyframe.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Share some code so we can help you.

Comment: I don't have any code yet, was hoping someone already had a library or similar that exists for this. Otherwise I guess I will need to write!

Comment: Unfortunately stackoverflow isn't supposed to be google.  Get some code and ask a specific question.